# The empty space while scrolling in Cordova/Ionic/iOS

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created the Ionic-Cordova application (iOS App).

At first, I removed the keyboard accessory bar.

The accessory bar has gone well. (picture below)

[image]

...But then when I scroll down to the bottom it shows an empty space (white space top of keyboard)

[image]

Can anyone figure out how to solve this one?

I'm not sure weather it's Cordova/iOS or Ionic/css issue, I tried to solve all of them but nothing works.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a known issue with Cordova and the keyboard plugin (which I assume Ionic is using). I'm not sure of a fix, ATM, sorry. :-( To be honest, I prefer keeping the accessory bar there, and leave it in all my pg apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
//Give your specifications here while editing
scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,285);
 //If you are using tableview,give the constraints for tableview
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
//Give your specifications here after editing completed
scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,586);
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess, you'd probably need to listen to the keyboard so that when it was shown, you could adjust the frame. This might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html. I'm not sure if it will work even then, though.